# strange things happened during implementation of hashmap in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, hash, hashmap

I try to implement my own hashmap in c++. 
My header is

```cpp
class MyMap
{
public:


    MyMap();
    ~MyMap();

    int get(int key) const;
    void put(int key, int value);
    bool containsKey(int key);
    Vector<int> keys() const;
    int size();

    void sanityCheck();
    MyMap(const MyMap &myMap); // copy constructor
    MyMap& operator= (const MyMap &myMap); // assignment overload
    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, MyMap &myMap);
    friend istream &operator>>(istream &in, MyMap &myMap);
private:

    struct key_val_pair {
        int key;
        int value;
        key_val_pair* next;
    };

    typedef key_val_pair** bucketArray; // just renaming the pointer to pointer.

    bucketArray createBucketArray(int nBuckets);
    int hashFunction(int input) const;

    bucketArray buckets;

    int nBuckets;
    int nElems;
    int INIT_N_BUCKETS = 128;

};
```

I initialize my map using

```cpp
MyMap::MyMap() {
   bucketArray buckets = createBucketArray(INIT_N_BUCKETS);
   nBuckets = INIT_N_BUCKETS;
   nElems = 0;
}
MyMap::bucketArray MyMap::createBucketArray(int nBuckets) {
    bucketArray newBuckets = new key_val_pair*[nBuckets];
    for (int i = 0; i < nBuckets; i++) {
        newBuckets[i] = nullptr;
    }
    return newBuckets;
```

}

And here is my code to put elements into hashmap

```cpp
void MyMap::put(int key, int value) {
    // compute hash;
    int bucket = hashFunction(key) % nBuckets ;
    key_val_pair *entry = buckets[bucket];    
    key_val_pair *prev = nullptr;
    if(entry == nullptr) {

        entry = new key_val_pair;
        entry->key = key;
        entry->value = value;
        entry->next = nullptr;
        buckets[bucket] = entry;
        nElems++;
    }
    else{
        while(entry && entry->key != key){
            prev = entry;
            entry = entry->next;
        }

        if(!entry){
            entry = new key_val_pair;
            entry->key = key;
            entry->value = value;
            entry->next = nullptr;
            if(!prev) buckets[bucket] = entry;
            else prev->next = entry;
            nElems++;
        }
        else{
            entry->value = value;
        }
    }

}
```

Now, here is the weird part, even just after initialization. For example, I let  `MyMap m = MyMap();` . And I input pairs (i, i), i from 0 to 100. I found that not all of my buckets[i] are null pointers(I added sentences in put such as `buckets[bucket] == null` )! before I put pairs in the map. Some are, but some are not! 
How come this things could happen? As I just initialized them all to `nullptr`?

FYI, inside of the constructor, I checked and all buckets[i] are indeed `nullptr`. This bug is driving me crazy.... 
Could someone help me on this? Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you want this; `new key_val_pair*[nBuckets];`? (*)

Comment: @Stefan Yes I think so, it is just an array of linked lists consist of (key, value) pairs.

Comment: This line: `bucketArray buckets = createBucketArray(INIT_N_BUCKETS);`? What happens if you remove `bucketArray` from it?

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring another bucketarray in the constructor but you don't assign it to your member from the class:

`bucketArray buckets = createBucketArray(INIT_N_BUCKETS);`

should be:

```
buckets = createBucketArray(INIT_N_BUCKETS);
```

Or even better, initialize all your members like this:

```
MyMap::MyMap()
:
INIT_N_BUCKETS(128),
buckets(createBucketArray(INIT_N_BUCKETS)),
nBuckets(INIT_N_BUCKETS),
nElems(0)
{ }
```

You have to move `INIT_N_BUCKETS` higher in the class too since the order matters when you initialize.

Example code:
https://ideone.com/b8RN1Q

Comment: @jack No problem :)